How do I find subspaces and quotients of the vector spaces $V_i$ such that the maps become injective and surjective?
Say I have linear maps $V_1 \xrightarrow{g} V_2 \xrightarrow{f}  V_3$. I want to find subspaces $W_i$ of $V_i$ such that I have linear maps $W_1 \xrightarrow{\bar{g}} W_2 \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} W_3$, and I am looking for the maps to be surjective and such that the subspaces are as large as can be.
Also, how about if I want to find Quotients $\bar{V}_i$ of $V_i$ such that I have linear maps $\bar{V}_1 \xrightarrow{\bar{g}} \bar{V}_2 \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} \bar{V}_3$ such that the maps are injective and the quotients as large as can be?

What exactly is the connection supposed to be between $f,g$ and $\bar f$ and $\bar g$? It's impossible to show that the answer to your question gives the largest possible subspaces unless we have some constraint on what kinds of functions $\bar f$ and $\bar g$ are permissible here.

One possible condition that might align with what you have in mind could be that there exist linear maps $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\bar f = \alpha \circ f \circ \beta$ and similarly for $g$

A reasonable meaning would be that there is a commutative diagram mapping the sequences which is a surjection on each term.

For the first problem, $W_1=V_1,W_2=g(W_1),W_3=fg(W_1)$, and similarly for the second problem $W_1=V_1/\text{ker}(fg), W_2=V_2/\text{ker}(f),W_3=V_3$

ADDED:
Any such sequence for the first problem $$W_1\overset{f_1}\to\cdots\overset{f_{n}}\to W_{n+1}$$ is determined by $W_1$. For the induced map to be well defined, then $W_2 \geq f_1(W_1)$, but if its any bigger then surjectivity is broken. And so on.
The quotient problem is just dual to the first problem so all the logic is similar.

Thanks, can you please also right a little something about why/how this is true?

@J.Doe Basically, you don't gain anything by making $W_3$ smaller since you would just be trying to make $W_2$ inject into a smaller space

I think the problem is less trivial if you ask for injective (resp. surjective) maps between subspaces (resp. quotient spaces). In that case making $W_3$ smaller makes it easier to surject onto (similarly taking $W_1$ smaller makes it easier to inject from)
